# Query in Priority Ordering

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We want brands to be in the first place and then an alphabetical order.

[image]

As we try to explain in the image, we want to sort the DAF brand first and then alphabetically of other brands.

Comment: Just another option  ...   order by nullif([Names],'DAF')

Comment: Also, please post sample data, desired results and attempt as formatted text rather than an image.

Comment: Please post code and data as text directly in the question not as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to SO! You can do this with a CASE statement in your ORDER BY:

```
ORDER BY CASE
         WHEN [name] = 'DAF'
         THEN ''
         ELSE [name]
     END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `case` statement in the `Order by` clause would work in most scenarios, but it will not work on its when you use a `select distinct`. You would have to either add the case statement as a field or throw a nested statement. Both the below statements would work:

```
select distinct name,
    NULLIF(name,'DAF') as dummy 
from Brands 
order by 
    NULLIF(name,'DAF')

select a.*
from
    (select distinct name
    from Brands) a
order by 
    NULLIF(a.name,'DAF')
```

You can also do the nested statement by using CTE. Hope this helps.